# Problem Deploying Fly.io App With Express/Node/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, deployment

have an app where it is having trouble deploying. It was already deployed but all of a sudden the link no longer worked. I tried to redeploy and it failed so I then deleted that app, cloned my github, and retried again to no avail. To give context, my old laptop broke and I had to get a new laptop but the app will not deploy properly. It uses Express, Node and Mongoose and only has a front-end.

Here is the current error that I am receiving:

```
 [1/1] Checking that e28677eb572286 [app] is up and running Smoke checks for e28677eb572286 failed: the app appears to be crashing Check its logs: here's the last lines below, or run 'fly logs -i e28677eb572286': INFO Starting init (commit: 0b28cec)... INFO Preparing to run:docker-entrypoint.sh npm run start` as root
INFO [fly api proxy] listening at /.fly/api
2023/06/23 20:04:23 listening on [fdaa:2:7b4:a7b:21a1:8e24:3a29:2]:22 (DNS: [fdaa::3]:53)

men_oauth@0.2.0 start
node ./bin/www.js
Fri, 23 Jun 2023 20:04:24 GMT express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option at file:/app/server.js:46:3
Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.
Listening on port 8080
/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:768
throw new MongooseError('The uri parameter to openUri() must be a ’ +
^
MongooseError: The uri parameter to openUri() must be a string, got “undefined”. Make sure the first parameter to mongoose.connect() or mongoose.createConnection() is a string.
at _createMongoClient (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:768:11)
at NativeConnection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:705:29)
at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:406:15)
at file:///app/config/database.js:7:10
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
Node.js v18.15.0
npm notice
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 9.5.0 → 9.7.2
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.7.2
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@9.7.2 to update!
npm notice
INFO Main child exited normally with code: 1
INFO Starting clean up.
WARN hallpass exited, pid: 232, status: signal: 15 (SIGTERM)
2023/06/23 20:04:25 listening on [fdaa:2:7b4:a7b:21a1:8e24:3a29:2]:22 (DNS: [fdaa::3]:53)
[ 3.130614] reboot: Restarting system
machine did not have a restart policy, defaulting to restart
INFO Starting init (commit: 0b28cec)…
INFO Preparing to run: docker-entrypoint.sh npm run start as root
INFO [fly api proxy] listening at /.fly/api
2023/06/23 20:04:26 listening on [fdaa:2:7b4:a7b:21a1:8e24:3a29:2]:22 (DNS: [fdaa::3]:53)
men_oauth@0.2.0 start
node ./bin/www.js
Fri, 23 Jun 2023 20:04:28 GMT express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option at file:/app/server.js:46:3
Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.
Listening on port 8080
/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:768
throw new MongooseError('The uri parameter to openUri() must be a ’ +
^
MongooseError: The uri parameter to openUri() must be a string, got “undefined”. Make sure the first parameter to mongoose.connect() or mongoose.createConnection() is a string.
at _createMongoClient (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:768:11)
at NativeConnection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:705:29)
at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:406:15)
at file:///app/config/database.js:7:10
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
Node.js v18.15.0
npm notice
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 9.5.0 → 9.7.2
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.7.2
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@9.7.2 to update!
npm notice
INFO Main child exited normally with code: 1
INFO Starting clean up.
WARN hallpass exited, pid: 232, status: signal: 15 (SIGTERM)
2023/06/23 20:04:28 listening on [fdaa:2:7b4:a7b:21a1:8e24:3a29:2]:22 (DNS: [fdaa::3]:53)
Error: smoke checks for e28677eb572286 failed: the app appears to be crashing
```

`

I have tried reinstalling fly.io, upgrading fly.io, deleting the toml file, flyscale count 1, flyscale count 2, and recloning the github code and redeploying.

Answer (score 1):

I just destroyed my app (**not a machine**) and then run `fly launch`. Use the same .toml file and it work fine.